# Content deployment quick-deploy job errors

Tags: 2007, publishing, content-deployment

SharePoint 2007 Enterprise, SP2 (no post-SP2 patches).

For some reason, after a content page was checked-in, published, and marked for quick deployment a couple days ago, our quick deploy job started failing with these errors:

> The object /ContentPage.aspx that was configured as part of the Export Settings no longer exists.

The page does exist, and has for a while - the version that had been recently published was version 9 of the page in question.  Re-publishing the page hasn't changed anything, and the ULS logs just repeat the error as seen in the deployment report in Central Admin.

Are there any good ways to start tracking this down and/or clearing this part of the job from the system? The page has since been moved to production via the nightly job without incident.

Comment: what cumulative update/service pack version are you on?

Comment: Edited top of the post for version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer so much as what we did; I deleted & recreated the content deployment path & jobs, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would strongly recommend installing the Post-SP2 patches to see if the issue is resolved. By my count there have been **thirteen** [cumulative update releases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839) for 2007 since SP2 thus far. From memory this feature set of the product was quite buggy when it was first released and it's quite likely bugs are continuing to be fixed for it.

Of course, you should install the updates in your development/test environment(s) first to ensure you have the process down pat and don't experience any problems as a result.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, the only thing I can suggest is opening a support case with Microsoft.